# Append <span>-tag to css header-element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

I've been trying to append this element after a css-class on my Wordpress site:

```
<span class="blink">_</span>
```

I can't change the file structure, but I can use CSS/Jquery. The code snippet works when I just put it in a random , but now I want to use CSS/Jquery to append it, so that all my post-headers are rounded off with the blinking underscore (_).

The code I have so far looks like this, but it doesn't work:

`$(".intro-title").after("<span class="blink">_</span>");`

I've tried with and without the ""'s before and after the -tag, still no luck.

If I do a

```
.intro-title::after { content: "Hello";}
```

it works perfectly fine. So I know that the Wordpress-setup allows me to append something after the header. I am also required to wrap my function into a tag like this:

```
jQuery(function($){ ... });
```

Hopefully, it will be possible to append my little blinking underscore to all h1's of the class "intro-title" - but for now I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to something like this.

```
$(".intro-title").after("<span class='blink'>_</span>");
```

```js
$(".intro-title").after("<span class='blink'>_</span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="intro-title">This is paragraph</p>
```

**Or using append.**

```js
$(".intro-title").append("<span class='blink'>_</span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="intro-title">This is paragraph</p>
```

**Using Css style**

```css
.intro-title::after{
 content:'_';
}
```

```html
<p class="intro-title">This is Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: It seems like the "append" instead of "after" did the trick. The final snippet looks like this: "jQuery(function($){$(".intro-title").append("<span class='blink'>_</span>");});"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.intro-title').after('<span class="blink">_</span>');
```

EDIT

Sorry @ADyson

In javascript string you can use single or double quote.
If you use single quote they don't match double quote and vice versa

```
var myString ='hello "world"';

var myString ="hello 'world'";
```

Comment: at the very least a minimal explanation of the answer would be nice. It might seem obvious to you, but clearly not to the OP otherwise they wouldn't have asked the question.